# Why doesn't this method for getting the difference between two dates work?

Tags: javascript

I am trying to test whether certain time has elapsed. I use javascript.

Both examples use this variable:

```
var delete_after = 2 /*minutes*/ * 60 /*seconds*/ * 1000/*miliseconds*/; // [miliseconds]
```

This works:

```
var now = new Date();
var now_t = now.getTime();
var then = new Date(x.time); // x.time is string with a time
var then_t = then.getTime();//).getTime();
if (now_t - then_t > delete_after) {
    alert("deleted");
}
```

This does not:

```
if (Date().getTime() - Date(x.time).getTime() > delete_after) {
    alert("deleted");
}
```

I belived them to be equivalent, but they are not. I checked precedence, in the end it appears I have to call new to create a variable. It seems to impossible to call (new Date().getTime()). Please, would You be so kind to explain why it can not be written the second way?

Comment: "Does not work" >.< Examine what each expression evaluates to, and you'll see pretty quickly what's going on.

Comment: You can use `Date.now()` instead of `var now = new Date(), now_t = now.getTime();`. There's a very simple compatibility shim in the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/now) for browsers that don't support `Date.now()`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

getTime is a function of date objects, not of the Date() function, so you have to call Date() to get a date object, and then call getTime on it.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

This would do it all in one go, but it's a bit confusing

```
(new Date()).getTime()
```

Comment: Mentioned in the link Tomalak provided.

Comment: What is the reason for having to create new object? I know it is in specs, but is there inability of javascript to have such implementation where AlternativeDate().getTime() would work?

Comment: @user712092: Javascript could have been designed to brew coffee if that had been intended; it was not.

Comment: @Lightnes: why not recommend that site?

Comment: @user712092: Click on the link I gave you and find out.

Answer (score 5):

- `Date().getTime()`

  is not the same as

  `(new Date()).getTime()`

---

- `Date(x.time).getTime()`

  is not the same as

  `(new Date(x.time)).getTime()`

Answer (score 3):

Well, if you want to do it in short, just do it like this:

```
if ((new Date()).getTime() - (new Date(x.time)).getTime() > delete_after) {
    alert("deleted");
}
```

Your example didn't work because object has to be instantiated before you perform any function call on it.